# Addon fails to enable after adding a new "Scripts" path without restarting

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, error, path

I've made an addon that needs to be in a specific shared `Scripts` folder but it fails to enable when the `Scripts` folder is first added.

To illustrate the problem I've used [Mesh Tiny CAD](https://github.com/zeffii/mesh_tiny_cad) since its freely available on github and has the same issue as me. All of these images are without restarting Blender.

This is where the script is in Windows:
[image: Windows explorer showing the location of the Mesh Tiny CAD addon]

I add the new custom `Scripts` path (IMPORTANT that this `Scripts` path isnt already added to Blender, it has to be added in the same session as the addon otherwise the error doesnt show up)
[image: Showing custom Scripts folder being added]

But when I try to enable the addon for the first time:
[image: Showing new addon in the Addons tab and the correct path]

Blender gives me this error saying the addon doesn't exist:
[image: Error message when enabling the addon]

If I then save preferences and restart Blender (with the new script path) the addon works
[image: Addon enables correctly after restarting Blender]

Is this an unavoidable situation with Blender or is there something that can be done to fix the problem?

Comment: sorry, but i couldn't reproduce your error with Zeffi's add-on. So either you do something different or maybe explain step by step how you produced the error?

Comment: I had hoped the images were clear but the crucial part is the adding of the custom Scripts path. Its only when I start Blender without a custom scripts path and then add a custom scripts path and then try to enable the addon (without restarting blender!) that this error shows up.
Did you add a new scripts path and then tried to enable the addon? If the path is already loaded at Blender startup the error doesnt show up

Comment: yes, i tried that. Did you try it with a newer blender version maybe?

Comment: Hmm strange. I've tested with both 3.3.1 and 3.0.0 and it happens in both, did you add the `Scripts` path on a different disk? I have Blender on C:\ and the shared folder on W:\ but I dont know if that matters

Comment: Can repro. Doing a "Reload Scripts" after setting the Scripts path will make it work. Doesn't seem like forcing a particular Scripts path is a good idea though (what if two addons did it?).

Comment: "Reload Scripts" fixes it for me too, nice find!
The script isn't meant for wide distribution but needs to be in a specific spot due to version control software. I guess this is as close to a solution as possible.